# Why function that is property of the object isn't accessible once we add the same function to its prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have some basic understanding of why we use prototypical inheritance, while doing some stuff in my app I realized you can't really access a function once you add the function of the same name to its prototype. Why is that, Here is my code:

```js
function person(firstname, lastname) {
    this.firstname = firstname,
    this.lastname = lastname,
    this.greet = function() {
        console.log('hey there', this.lastname + '  ' + this.firstname);
    }
}

var jane = new person('jane', 'Doe');
jane.greet();
var john = new person('john', 'smith');
john.greet();

function person(firstname, lastname) {
    this.firstname = firstname,
    this.lastname = lastname
}

person.prototype.greet = function() {
    console.log('hey there', this.lastname + '  ' + this.firstname);
}

var jane = new person('jane', 'Doe');
jane.greet();
var john = new person('john', 'smith');
john.greet();
```

Error thrown is:

```
"test.js:10
jane.greet();
     ^
TypeError: jane.greet is not a function"
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the prototype but rather with hoisting of the redeclaration of `person`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works for me. The only issue I could think of is you have re-declared (or tried to re-declare) the same method `person` within the same code block.

**Edit** for clarification: As pointed out by ASDFGerte, the second declaration of `person` overwrites the first version, which removes the internal method `greet`. You then try to use `greet` before the `prototype` expands `person` and re-adds the `greet` function.

```js
function person(firstname, lastname) {
    this.firstname = firstname,
    this.lastname = lastname,
    this.greet = function() {
        console.log('hey there', this.lastname + '  ' + this.firstname);
    }
}
var jane = new person('jane', 'Doe');
jane.greet();
var john = new person('john', 'smith');
john.greet();

function person2(firstname, lastname) {
    this.firstname = firstname,
    this.lastname = lastname
}
person2.prototype.greet = function() {
    console.log('(2) hey there', this.lastname + '  ' + this.firstname);
}
var jane2 = new person2('jane2', 'Doe');
jane2.greet();
var john2 = new person2('john2', 'smith');
john2.greet();
```

Comment: As i already said, function declarations get hoisted along with initialization, his error even says line 10, the first time he makes `jane` there is just no `greet`. The prototype gets set later in the code.

Comment: @ASDFGerte : Thanks, added clarification with credit.

Comment: Thanks mate.:) and yes I was experimenting in same block.